# Autofac register same interface with different constructors

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am using latest Autofac and would like to register the same type and interface twice based on different constructors

My class/interface

```
public partial class MyDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString, bool proxyCreationEnabled, bool lazyLoadingEnabled, bool autoDetectChangesEnabled)
        : base(connectionString)
    {            
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChangesEnabled;


        InitializePartial();
    }

}
```

In my autofac setup i am registering via ..

```
        builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IMyDbContext>()
            .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionString", (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

How do I register the 2nd constructor, with Autofac so that i can use it via constructor injection on different classes? I was thinking something like the following but then how does Autofac know which class to inject.

```
        //builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IMyDbContext>()
        //    .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionString", (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString)
        //    .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "proxyCreationEnabled", (pi, c) => false)
        //    .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "lazyLoadingEnabled", (pi, c) => false)
        //    .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "autoDetectChangesEnabled", (pi, c) => false)
        //    .Named<MyDbContext>("MyDbContextReadOnly")
        //    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: I think your question should be how can I register type with parameters. You should choose one constructor. If you want to use more than one create a factory class and register factory beside of your class.

Comment: http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but not confident it is best possible.  I created new IMyDbContextReadonly interface for class MyDbContextReadonly which has the constructor that I want to use.

```
    public interface IMyDbContextReadonly : IMyDbContext { }

public class MyDbContextReadonly : MyDbContext, IMyDbContextReadonly
{
    public MyDbContextReadonly(string connectionString, bool proxyCreationEnabled, bool lazyLoadingEnabled, bool autoDetectChangesEnabled)
        : base(connectionString)
    {            
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChangesEnabled;
    }
}
```

Then within the Autofac configuration I registered like..

```
            builder.RegisterType<MyDbContextReadonly>().As<IMyDbContextReadonly>()
                .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionString", (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString)
                .WithParameter("proxyCreationEnabled", false)
                .WithParameter("lazyLoadingEnabled", false)
                .WithParameter("autoDetectChangesEnabled", false)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This works, but again, is this the correct approach? thx

Comment: No, i do not think is the correct approach. You can find the correct one here:
http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html